# Purpose of Charge Pump in Motor Driver IC

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor, charge-pump

I have seen and understood the purpose of charge pumps. Used for pumping voltage levels in case of RS232 transceiver IC's. But most of the motor driver IC's also includes a internal charge pump circuitry. What is the exact purpose of this? As voltage required for the motor is already been given through external source.

Comment: Impossible to say generally. But perhaps to drive the H-bridge transistors?

Answer (score 4):

You have to drive the gate of the N-channel Power FET in the driver chip high enough to make the FET switch fully on.  Since the chip is using N-Channel MOS-FETs in the high side of the H-Bridge, you have to provide a voltage higher than the motor source to make the gate switch on. The chips include a charge pump to generate the needed voltage so that you don't have to implement it separately.

See also [this question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164711/why-use-a-n-channel-mosfet-as-high-side-h-bridge-switches)

This isn't a very good answer, but should provide enough key words for you to find more information on your own - and maybe one of the resident experts will provide a more detailed answer later on.